# Please help me assess the correctness of my question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, quality-improvement

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Numbering insensitive to delete row in Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59626841/numbering-insensitive-to-delete-row-in-google-sheets)

Please help me assess the correctness of my question and my next steps (my edits)?

I would like to use SO correct, but I don't know how better I should ask in this case.

Why did I get -1 even though I made an effort?

Please be specific and critical.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205555/discussion-on-question-by-ogi22-please-help-me-assess-the-correctness-of-my-ques). If you have an opinion you want to share, post an answer.

Comment: @CodyGray Thanks for warning. Then why is there a term "discussion"? I don't think removing all the comments from this post is useful because they might have hidden a valuable and helpful answer for someone. Is it possible to undo them? Or how does another user access them?

Comment: Ogi22, you could read the comment from Cody, there is a link to the comments and he wrote what people are supposed to do when participating in the discussion: post an answer.

Comment: Comments are not answers. The [discussion] tag means that you’re soliciting input/opinions from the community. That is OK on Meta, but these opinions should still be posted as answers, not comments. When there gets to be more than 25 or 30 comments, they’re too hard to read. I’ve archived the comments that used to be here in chat, so they’re not lost forever. Click the link to see them.